# typescript: указать тип данных для подгружаемых данных из файла

Tags: reactjs, typescript, импорт, typescript-типы

у меня есть файл, в котором содержится данные в формате json

```
[
    {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
    {"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"},
    ...
]
```

загружаю их так:

```
import countriesInfo from '../jsons/countries.json'
```

можно ли как-то указать, какой тип у данных (`IType_Country[]`)

```
// интерфейс для данных о странах
export interface IType_Country {
    name:           string,         // название страны
    code:           string          // буквенный код страны
}
```

, чтобы затем я корректно мог их использовать:

```
const countries: IType_Country[] = countriesInfo.filter((obj: IType_Country) => obj.name == countryName);
```

Без указания типа тоже все работает, но Visual Studio Code просто подчёркивает строчку кода:

```
any
Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65779894/1016033

Comment: то, что надо - спасибо